# Adding debugging facilities to boost variant visitor

Tags: c++, crtp, boost-variant, visitor-pattern

I'm using `boost-variant` throughout my projects and I'm considering it to be one the most useful and versatile tools of `boost`.

But if it comes to complicated use of the visitor pattern with recursively nested variants the debugging is sometimes cumbersome.

Hence I decided to implement a reusable `DebugVisitor`, that might be added to my existing visitors. It should be easily added/removed to my existing visitors in case a defect occurs.

Easily removable means, that it should be addable to any existing Visitor class, instead of modifying the places, where instances of the Visitor are being used.

I tried to find a solution, which fits my requirements. The following code compiles, but unfortunately it does not print the message.

Does anyone knows why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <functional>

template<typename V> // V must have the boost::static_visitor Interface
struct DebugVisitor : public V {
    template<typename U>
    typename V::result_type operator()(const U& u) const {
        std::cout << "Visiting Type:" << typeid(U).name() << " with Visitor: " << typeid(V).name() << std::endl;
        return V::operator()(u);
    }
};


struct AddVisitor : public DebugVisitor<boost::static_visitor<boost::variant<int, double>>> {
    template<typename U>
    result_type operator()(const U& u) const {
        return u + 1.;
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    boost::variant<double, int> number{ 3.2 };

    AddVisitor d;
    auto incr=number.apply_visitor(d);
    if (auto dValue = boost::get<double>(incr)) {
        std::cout << "Increment: " << dValue << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first example uses `T` but does not define it

Comment: @Caleth: Thanks. I removed my old solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you don't see debug output is because `AddVisitor::operator()` does not call `DebugVisitor::operator()`. If it did, you would have an error trying to resolve `boost::static_visitor<>::operator()`, which *doesn't exist*.

Option 1.

Just conditionally compile the debugging in the definition of `AddVisitor`

```
struct AddVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<boost::variant<int, double>> {
    template<typename U>
    result_type operator()(const U& u) const {
#ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << "Visiting Type:" << typeid(U).name() << " with Visitor: " << typeid(AddVisitor).name() << std::endl;
#endif
        return u + 1.;
    }
};
```

Option 2.

Conditionally define the symbol `AddVisitor` to be wrapped by `DebugVisitor`

```
template<typename V> // V must have the boost::static_visitor Interface
struct DebugVisitor : public V {
    template<typename U>
    typename V::result_type operator()(const U& u) const {
        std::cout << "Visiting Type:" << typeid(U).name() << " with Visitor: " << typeid(V).name() << std::endl;
        return V::operator()(u);
    }
};

struct AddVisitorBase : public boost::static_visitor<boost::variant<int, double>> {
    template<typename U>
    result_type operator()(const U& u) const {
        return u + 1.;
    }
};

#ifdef DEBUG
using AddVisitor = DebugVisitor<AddVisitorBase>;
#else
using AddVisitor = AddVisitorBase;
#endif
```

Option 3.

A pair of CRTP bases

```
template<typename V> // V must have the boost::static_visitor Interface
struct DebugVisitor : public V {
    template<typename U>
    typename V::result_type operator()(const U& u) const {
        std::cout << "Visiting Type:" << typeid(U).name() << " with Visitor: " << typeid(V).name() << std::endl;
        return V::call(u);
    }
};

template<typename V> // V must have the boost::static_visitor Interface
struct NotDebugVisitor : public V {
    template<typename U>
    typename V::result_type operator()(const U& u) const {
        return V::call(u);
    }
};

struct AddVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<boost::variant<int, double>>, public 
#ifdef DEBUG
DebugVisitor<AddVisitor>
#else
NotDebugVisitor<AddVisitor>
#endif
{
    template<typename U>
    result_type call(const U& u) const {
        return u + 1.;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it unfortunately doesn't fit my requirement. Assume, that I'm using AddVisitor in scattered place all around my project. Now, something went wrong and I wanted to add Debugging facilities to all of my AddVisitor's. Then I have to replace it in every place. It would be nice, if I could somehow add the debugging facility right to AddVisitor.

Comment: Nice. Is there some way to avoid having AddVisitorBase and AddVisitor?

Comment: Not really. You can hide AddVisitorBase in a namespace

Comment: A solution like `struct AddVisitor : public DebugVisitor<AddVisitor<boost::variant<int, double>>` is not possible?

Comment: You'd still have to change `operator()`, so that you don't hide the one inherited from `DebugVisitor`

Comment: Is there some way to avoid the hiding? I was not aware, that there is some hiding.

Comment: When you have `Base::foo()` and `Derived::foo()`, and pass around `Derived`s, the only `foo` that get called is `Derived::foo()`. This is called "hiding"

Comment: Very cool solution towards the end. I was also not aware of `call` either. Many thanks for your thorough solution.

Comment: `call` is just a normal function. You can name it whatever you like

Comment: Ouch. I thought it to be a substitute for operator(). Sorry.

Comment: Ah. Now I fully understand the solution. I should have looked more carefully.

Comment: Seems that I have to touch existing code and changing operator() to call()?

Comment: If you want to use option 3, yes, you need to have the `DebugVisitor` define `operator()`, and `AddVisitor` have a method named for whatever `DebugVisitor` calls. The problem you started with is that an `AddVisitor::operator()` would mean that calling code would ignore `DebugVisitor::operator()`.

Comment: However, I have presented these in order of most recommended to least recommended